# How to read CSV files which have description and comment lines at the top?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have many csv files which I have to read into a dataframe. Only problem is that they all have a description and metadata in the first 4 lines like this:

```
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2006-11-02 00:00:08
```

After these, I have a normal csv data. How to deal with this? I could remove them manually, only problem is that i have too many such files.

Comment: does `pd.read_csv(...,comment='#')` work ?

Comment: Accept any answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `skip_rows` parameter of `pd.read_csv()`.

According to documentation:

`skip_rows`: Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file. So call it like this:

`df = pd.read_csv("path_tocsv.csv", skip_rows= lambda x: x in [0, 1, 2, 3])`

The advantage of this is that this way is we can determine which rows to skip and which to not. Otherwise simple passing `skip_rows=4` skips first 4 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Simply skip the first 4 rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file", skiprows=4)
```